# 'which' is unable to find command even though it is definitely installed

Tags: linux, debian, command, path, which

I have recently installed the `cryptsetup`. I've double checked with `sudo apt-get install cryptsetup`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
cryptsetup is already the newest version (2:2.3.7-1+deb11u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However when I try to use the command it does not recognize it.

```
bash: cryptsetup: command not found
```

Then I tried to find the location of the command using `which`.
`which cryptsetup`

However the command does not return anything. `man cryptsetup` says that `cryptsetup` indeed is the right command name. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 15):

`cryptsetup` is installed in `/sbin`, which isn’t on users’ `PATH` by default; as a result, `which` can’t find it.

If you run `which` as root, it should find `cryptsetup`:

```
$ which cryptsetup
cryptsetup not found
$ sudo which cryptsetup
/sbin/cryptsetup
```

(Regarding `which`, see [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/86440))

Comment: Instead of generically not using `which`, for the particular case where you've installed a package on a Debian system, run `dpkg-query -L cryptsetup` (or whatever). It'll list the files installed by the package. There are of course equivalents for other package managers.